# React state updated too late

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Hope everything is going well for you.
I have a trouble with my React code and I can't figure out why.
Here are my classes : Profil and couleur. A Profil contains a list of couleurs.

```
export interface Profil {
    id: number;
    referenceProduit: string;
    type: string;
    longueur: number;
    prixMetreLineaire: number;
    quantiteOuMl: number;
    prixUnitaire: number;
    couleurs: Couleur[];
}

export interface Couleur{
    id:number|null;
    nomCouleur:string;
    metreLineaire:number;
}
```

I use a state that is used to set and show some part of the profil :

```
    const [profil, setProfil] = useState<Profil | null>(null)
```

I use it in this JSX fragment :

```
{profil && (
                    <>
                        <Row>
                            <Col>

                                Référence : <span>{profil.referenceProduit}</span>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <Col>
                                Qr code :

                            </Col>
                            <Col>
                                <Barcode value={profil.id.toString()} format="CODE39"/>
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <Col>
                                Couleurs et tailles :
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                        {profil.couleurs.map(
                            (item) => (
                                <>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Col>
                                            Nom couleur :

                                        </Col>
                                        <Col>
                                            {item.nomCouleur}
                                        </Col>

                                    </Row>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Col>
                                            Metres linéaires :

                                        </Col>
                                        <Col>
                                            {item.metreLineaire}
                                        </Col>
                                    </Row>
                                </>
                            )
                        )}
                        <br/>
                        <br/>

                        <Row>
                            {
                                isEditingColors ? (
                                    <>
                                        <Row>
                                            <Col>
                                                Nom couleur
                                            </Col>
                                            <Col>
                                                <FormControl
                                                    type="text"
                                                    name="nomCouleur"
                                                    value={couleurToBeEdited.nomCouleur}
                                                    onChange={handleInputChangeNewColor}
                                                    autoFocus
                                                />
                                            </Col>
                                        </Row>
                                        <Row>
                                            <Col>
                                                Nombre de metres linéaires
                                            </Col>
                                            <Col>
                                                <FormControl
                                                    type="text"
                                                    name="metreLineaire"
                                                    value={couleurToBeEdited.metreLineaire}
                                                    onChange={handleInputChangeNewColor}
                                                    autoFocus
                                                />
                                            </Col>
                                        </Row>
                                        <Row>
                                            <Button onClick={saveColor}>Sauvegarder</Button>
                                        </Row>
                                    </>

                                ) : (
                                    <>
                                        <Col>
                                            <Button onClick={editColors}>
                                                Ajouter une couleur
                                            </Button>
                                        </Col>
                                    </>
                                )
                            }

                        </Row>

                    </>
                )
                }
```

As you can see I have a button to create a new color with a form :

```
<>
                                        <Row>
                                            <Col>
                                                Nom couleur
                                            </Col>
                                            <Col>
                                                <FormControl
                                                    type="text"
                                                    name="nomCouleur"
                                                    value={couleurToBeEdited.nomCouleur}
                                                    onChange={handleInputChangeNewColor}
                                                    autoFocus
                                                />
                                            </Col>
                                        </Row>
                                        <Row>
                                            <Col>
                                                Nombre de metres linéaires
                                            </Col>
                                            <Col>
                                                <FormControl
                                                    type="text"
                                                    name="metreLineaire"
                                                    value={couleurToBeEdited.metreLineaire}
                                                    onChange={handleInputChangeNewColor}
                                                    autoFocus
                                                />
                                            </Col>
                                        </Row>
                                        <Row>
                                            <Button onClick={saveColor}>Sauvegarder</Button>
                                        </Row>
                                    </>
```

The problem is when I try to saveThecolor to persit it in my Spring boot app :

```
    function saveColor(){
        addingColorInArray();
        updateProfil();
        setIsEditingColors(false);
    }

    const addingColorInArray = () => {
        setProfil((prevProfil) => {
            if (prevProfil) {
                return {
                    ...prevProfil!,
                    couleurs: [
                        ...prevProfil.couleurs!,
                        couleurToBeEdited
                    ]
                };
            }
            return prevProfil; 
        });
    };

    const updateProfil = async () => {
        try {
            
            console.log('old value');
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/profils', {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(profil),
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                console.log('Objet mis à jour avec succès.');
                if(objet){
                    fetchProfil(objet.id.toString());
                    renderDetails();
                }
                
            } else {
                console.error('Erreur lors de la mise à jour de l\'objet.');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Erreur lors de la mise à jour:', error);
        }
    };
```

I don't know why but the value used to fetch the api is not up to date and the hook I use to show when there is a modification on the value of my state is triggered after the call to my API  :

```
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Profil up to date :", profil);
    }, [profil]);
```

So I see in the logs : 'old value' and then the modified profil with the couleur added to the array
If someone could help me please.
Thanks in advance :)

I tried some async things but I'm quite new to React so don't know much to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

React state value will only change on render, so at the time you called fetch, `profil` will still be the old value. I would suggest you send

```
{
  ...prevProfil!,
  couleurs: [
    ...prevProfil.couleurs!,
    couleurToBeEdited
  ]
}
```

as body instead of the `profil` state.

As stated in [React's official document](https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#setstate): Calling setState does not change the current state in the already executing code.